# Html video with .h264 extension

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

It is possible to read in Html the Videos with Extension .h264 with the Video Tag
For example:

```
<video width = "400" controls autoplay>
       <source src = "video.h264" type = "video / mp4">
</video>
```

Many thanks in advance!!
Alberto

Answer (score 0):

For raw streams like h264 saved in a .h264 file, the answer is no if we talk about just HTML5. HTML5 expects a container format and there are no ways to work around that.

This does become possible with the new [WebCodecs API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebCodecs_API), but this is a young standard. Compatibility is already [fairly strong](https://caniuse.com/webcodecs) though.

A custom approach of decoding via the many ffmpeg ports that exist is also a possibility, though a jackhammer solution. Here is an [.h264 player using that apporach](https://github.com/131/h264-live-player). Of course, that is a massive dependency.

Answer (score 0):

.h264 is a video codec used in MP4 files. Using a .h264 extension in the src attribute might not work as expected.
You can convert your .h264 video file into a  supported format like .mp4 and then use the converted file in your HTML code.

Answer (score -1):

h.264 is the encoding of the video.
the extension you want to use is the container of the video.  Typically for h264 video that would be mp4.

```
<source src = "video.mp4" type = "video / mp4">
```

Doug

Comment: The question refers to a raw h264 stream saved in a .h264 file, no media containers like .mp4 or .mkv involved.